# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

Getting this error:

Node found at: /Users/imac/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node
/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/icabPassenger-gfgrvbjpkajjdzgjpdcfdaxmmrrf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/hermes-engine.build/Script-46EB2E00024D70.sh: line 9: /Users/imac/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node: No such file or directory.

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Already tried

- Pod Install
- Clean build folder
- Open the Xcode project folder in your Terminal app. Enter and execute the following command: pod deintegrate Execute this command: pod install Re-open Xcode > go to Product > Clean Build Folder. Run your app again.
- if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
  echo "Symlinked..."
  source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
  fi